# Per-environment heading in thmtools theorems

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

I have a custom style for definitions, but I'd like to customize the heading every time:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=\topsep,
    spacebelow=\topsep,
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    numbered=no,
]{defsty}
\declaretheorem[style=defsty]{defn}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{defn}[Open set]
Open set definition here.
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

The above code should result in
**Open set.** Open set definition here.

Instead the result is
**Defn** (Open set). Open set definition here.

I tried to pass a custom name argument to the `defn` environment, but it does not work:

```
\begin{defn}[name=Open set]
...
\end{defn}
```

The thing is, I have many definitions, so I cannot declare a theorem for every one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. Note it would be simpler to do with `ntheorem` as it defines an `empty` theorem style, which has only an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=\topsep,
    spacebelow=\topsep,
    name=\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font},
    notefont=\bfseries,
    notebraces={}{},
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    numbered=no,
]{defsty}
\declaretheorem[style=defsty]{defn}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}[Open set]
Open set definition here.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Added:**

With the `ntheorem` package in the place of `amsthm`, the preamble should only contain these lines (`theoremtools` would be unnecessary for this problem):

\usepackage[amsmath, thref, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{empty}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{defn}{}

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! If I understand correctly, you've set name to be a single space? I've got a question, what does `\font` do? I get the warning: `Don't use "\font" in Latex documents`. However, if I replace it with `\normalfont` it fails with `missing font identifier`.

Comment: I didn't add a single space: I deleted the `interword space` (`\fontdimen 2\font`) that `amsthm/thmtools` insert, for some reason, at the beginning of the line when there is no theorem name. I have no such warning on my system. `\font` is the  identifier for the current font, and I don't know how to do without it.